# Regular expression to parse specific set of data

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I am using java and parsing string of data which have variable length of data as shown below,

```
kv {
  key "prefix"
  str_value "prefix1"
}
kv {
  key "init"          
  int_value 1        
}
kv {
  key "init"          
  }
```

As we can see that last kv tag have one value field missing but still valid. Wondering what regular expression i should be using to retrieve any data between  kv {} tag as shown below.

key "prefix" str_value "prefix1"

key "init" int_value 1

key "init"

Here is the code i am using to get kv delimiters.

```
scan = new Scanner(new File(this.getFileName())).useDelimiter(".*kv\\s*\\{\\s*[^}].*+");
System.out.println(scan.next());
```

Comment: You should probably not be using regular expressions to try to parse over multiple lines, especially with that regex as a "delimiter".  Regex is powerful but not always the right tool for the job.  A simple token-based parser is probably what you need.

Comment: @JimGarrison For token based parser, should i be reading line by line and check each string "startswith" or any other efficient way of doing with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this pattern should do the trick:

```
kv\s*\{\s*key\s+"([^"]*)"\s*(str_value\s+"([^"]*)"|int_value\s+(\d+))?\s*\}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sF6oZ0/1)

You could find all the matches and read the value of the first, third and fourth groups of each match in order to retrieve the key/value pairs.

However, if all you want to do is capture everything between the curly brackets, regardless of what it is, then you could do something much simpler:

```
kv\s*\{([^}]*)}
```

Then just read the value of the first group from each match.

Comment: Hi Steve, I am concerned about any thing inside kv{ } tag. So not specifically concerned with str_value or int_value

Comment: If you want to capture everything between the curly brackets, then just add a capturing group around that whole thing and read its value.

Comment: This solution is pretty close for what i am looking for.  kv\s*\{([^}]*)}, but if i am putting it in delimiter it is giving me every thing except what i need. Meaning it is considering kv{ }  as delimiter and skipping every thing including that matches kv\s*\{([^}]*)}. How can i do reverse of it?

Comment: Don't use it as a delimiter. Loop through the list of matches and read the value of the first group in each match. If you must use the regex as a delimiter, you could use (\}\s*)?key\s*\{

Comment: Oops. I meant kv, not key